# INNER JOIN is not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables: `questions`, and `tracking`.

`questions` holds the columns `id` and `url`.

`tracking` holds the columns `q_id` and `user_id`.

What I want to do is to select a random url for all rows, except where `q_id` = `id` and where `user_id` is equal to the `$_SESSION["id"]` ($id).

Here's my query:

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT url FROM questions 
        INNER JOIN tracking ON 
        questions.id != tracking.q_id 
        WHERE tracking.user_id = '$id' 
        LIMIT 1 ORDER BY RAND()");

$rows = $results->fetch_array();
```

The query I am doing is not working for some reason, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "is not working" means what? having too many results, not any results, an error?

Comment: @Jeff It's not producing any results

Comment: can you please try this  "SELECT url FROM questions LEFT JOIN tracking ON  questions.id = tracking.q_id 
               WHERE questions.id NOT in (SELECT tracking.q_id FROM tracking)  and tracking.user_id = '$id'  LIMIT 1 ORDER BY RAND()"

Comment: @GeordyJames With that query I am getting the error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object

Comment: is q_id foreignkey of questions

Comment: @GeordyJames Yes it is

Comment: Oke then try this "SELECT url FROM questions LEFT JOIN tracking ON questions.id = tracking.q_id WHERE questions.id NOT in (SELECT tracking.q_id FROM tracking) and tracking.user_id = '$id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 "

Answer (score 0):

Following is the query which I worked for me in SQL.

```
SELECT top 1 url FROM Questions 
        INNER JOIN Tracking ON 
        Questions.id != Tracking.qId
        WHERE tracking.UserId = 1 
        ORDER BY NEWID()
```

For MySQL, you can try "ORDER BY uuid()"

That should resolve your issue.

Thanks and regards,
Chetan Ranpariya